# WiFi keeps disconnecting on Linux(Elementary OS 6.1) (WiFi Driver RTL8821CE)

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, elementary-os

as mentioned in the question, my WiFi keeps disconnecting every 5 minutes or so.
I am on Elementary OS (6.1), I had the same issue with Ubuntu 20.04 a couple of days ago before switching.

I tried some of the suggestions on other questions but to no avail, any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: You could have a look into your syslog to find the cause. You might want to try a different driver for your network card.

Comment: See here https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce#unstable-connection---slowdowns-or-dropouts